# How to judge whether a local pc machine supports d2d hardware acceleration

Tags: gpu, direct2d, hardware-acceleration, rasterize

Hardware acceleration is a feature supported by Direct2D. Here is my question.

As far as I know, Hardware acceleration is limited by GPU model, driver version .etc. Does anybody know the details of this? In other words, how to determine whether a computer supports d2d hardware acceleration.

The image below is captured in Chrome browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this entirely depends on whether your hardware is capable of doing Direct3D 10/11. If you're able to create ID3D10Device/ID3D11Device explicitly specifying hardware mode, then Direct2D should also work in hardware. Note that it's a bit more complicated on Direct2D side, because some render target types do not work with hardware mode, and you also can specify render target options to explicitly ask for hardware mode, using `D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the DirectX capabilities of any Windows-based PC by running `DXDiag.exe` and clicking on the "Display" tab.

In 2018 you would be hard-pressed to find a PC that didn't support hardware acceleration.  Most systems these days support DirectX 11 at the least and this has more or less been the case since Windows 7.

Unless you're targeting Windows XP or Vista this simply isn't an issue.